# Referring to cell relative to a ActiveX commandbutton VBA

Tags: excel, button, vba

I have a lot of ActiveX command buttons on a lot of different worksheets in Excel.

When any of the buttons is clicked i want to put a string in the cell next to the button.

So far this has been quite bothersome as i can't ask the `TopLeftCell` of the button as with a `Form control` button, only the `Top` and `Left` values of the control. It's not trivial to transform these to a Row and Column since there are a lot of varying cell heights/widths in every sheet.

I want to prevent hardcoding a cell position in every `button_Click()` so i can move the button around without problems, modify the sheet,... and so i don't have to change the code of every single button when suddenly the text has to appear 2 cells next to the button instead of 1 cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this class module approach as outlined [here by Andrew Poulson](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?219122-Application-Caller-with-Command-Buttons-on-a-sheet) to cater for all the buttons

I didn't understand your comment re `TopLeftCell` - it is available for an ActiveX button

**`Class Module`**

```
`named as Class1

Public WithEvents ButtonGroup As CommandButton

Private Sub ButtonGroup_Click()
    Sheets(ButtonGroup.Parent.Name).Cells(ButtonGroup.TopLeftCell.Row, ButtonGroup.TopLeftCell.Column) = "Done"
End Sub
```

**`Normal Module`**

```
Dim Buttons() As New Class1

Sub Class_Init()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Obj As OLEObject
    Dim ButtonCount As Integer
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each Obj In Sh.OLEObjects
            If TypeName(Obj.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
                ButtonCount = ButtonCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve Buttons(1 To ButtonCount)
                Set Buttons(ButtonCount).ButtonGroup = Obj.Object
            End If
        Next Obj
    Next Sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ! And you're absolutely right, the topleftcell is available for ActiveX buttons aswell